# Javascript nested functions - what are the differences?

Tags: javascript, function

I am pondering on the following Javascript best practice pattern. I have a function in my code that has some nested functions. which of the following patterns should be preferred and why?

```
function parent() {
    function child1() {
        //child 1 code
    }

    function child2() {
        //child2 code
    }
    //parent code
    return {
        child1: child1,
        child2: child2
    };
}
```

or

```
function parent() {
    var child1 = function () {
        //child 1 code
    };
    var child2 = function () {
        //child2 code
    };
    //parent code
    return {
        child1: child1,
        child2: child2
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you need [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: @FCL This has nothing to see with codereview.

Comment: @ShaiAharoni Assigning functions to a variable makes it easier to pass them around as parameters to other function. To me, the second one is favorable for this reason.

Comment: @dystroy, may be you are right, but am not framework class library;)

Comment: Whoever clicked **primarily opinion-based** clearly did not read the answer.

Comment: @peim not "easier", "more obvious the same works". Still a valid reason, even if you're going to grow out of it ;-)

Comment: @vbence hmm... I think the question is much better after my edit than before. Do you think the same?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yep, I agree, it's clearly a better approach. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference between those two versions is that with

```
var a = function(){ ...
```

the function is `undefined` until this line (but the variable exists) while in

```
function a() { ...
```

the function is defined since the start of the enclosing function :

```
console.log(a); // logs "function a(){ return 2} "
console.log(b); // logs "undefined"
function a(){ return 2};
var b = function(){ return 2};
```

As Jan points out, the first version also defines the `name` property of the function.

Other than that, there's no difference and it's mainly a matter of style, with no best practice I know.

Comment: `a.name` can also distinguish these two

Comment: (also note I voted to close)

Comment: @JanDvorak I saw. But while the title leads to think it's a matter of opinion I don't think those words ask only for an opinion : *"better or more correct"*.

Comment: Maybe an edit would solve that; but at least one or two other answers already are pure opinion. Should I have edited instead of closing?

Comment: (I've downvoted the one that's pure opinion)

Answer (score -1):

All named functions in js are accessible by their names.

another suggestion would be.

```
var parent;

parent = function() {
  var child1, child2;
  child1 = function() {};
  child2 = function() {};
  return {
    child1: child1,
    child2: child2
  };
};
```

Comment: They're not *exactly* the same (see my answer).

Comment: Hmm... what's the benefit of your suggestion over those two offered by the asker?

Comment: There is no benefit. 
Just the fact that the single var patern is used.

Comment: yeah, it's not axactly the same, keeping in mind the execution flow of javascript.